# Import CSV into Excel without text wrapping

Tags: excel, csv, import, datatable

This code pulls in a CSV file but it causes problems down the line as it WRAPS the text, how do I stop text wrapping as part of the import process?

Extract below:

```
Sub CSV_Import()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Import").Visible = True

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Import") 'destination sheet

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
End With
```

See pics below - Someone has put in comments in column N in the CSV file (See Orange pic wrapped text) and these have been split over 3 rows (Yellow pic) after import but into column A (which is for name not comments) instead of just one row (Green pic this is how col N should look like) once import complete. Blue pic is col N after the import is complete (3 blank rows as those comments split into col A).

The import is not doing the wrapping, the CSV itself has wrapped that cell (Can see that when I open CSV on its own), so I want to know how to unwrap that cell as part of the import procedure is that possible? or turn text wrapping off altogether as part of the import of the data in the CSV, is that an option?

[image: Orange is the wrapped cell in the CSV file column N]

[image: Green is the expected result (Unwrapped) in column N]

[image: Yellow is what happens after I run the import of the CSV file where it puts those comments from column N over 3 rows in column A (Which is for Names not comments)]

[image: Blue is col N after import. Only has part of the comments the rest are split into col A over 3 rows (Yellow)]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us (by samples) how does this macro wraps your text? What was the expected output?

Comment: Added pics and more explanation above.

Comment: Is column A preformatted with text wrapping switched on? If I try this out, the wrapping only occurs when this is the case. However, in both cases, Excel modifies the width of column A, which is pretty annoying.

Comment: If there are carriage returns in the file already, you can find and replace carriage returns in the cell (replace with nothing)

Comment: No. Only col N is wrapped and only in the cell where that long comment was inputted.

Comment: Are you aware this CSV import does create an updateable query to the text file which is stored in the Excel sheet?  That will annoy you, for example, with warnings when the text file isn't there any more. Or do you look for a solution which really puts the CSV content into your Excel sheet as if you had entered it manually?

Comment: If I go into the CSV hit the cell with the long comment I can uncheck the wrap text button and all good but don't want to do this, want to import file and as part of import process not have wrapped text. Can do this with PowerQuery but.. issue is some end users do not have latest Excel so need to use this code.

Comment: @Derek: if you can uncheck the text wrapping later, this means the column **is** preformatted with text wrapping, as I asked you before (but you said "no", so please check again). You can either uncheck manually before, manually later, or programmatically `ws.Columns("A:A").WrapText = False`.

Comment: If I highlight the whole col N the wrap text button is not pressed only when I select cell N17. I can only uncheck the wrapping in the CSV file cell N17 before I import it.

Comment: @Derek: select column N completely, check and uncheck the "Wrap Text" button. Then try again. Or see my answer below.

Comment: Can do that but don't want to manually go into the CSV file each time as want to do this as part of the import process.Tried your code but I am not sure how to incorporate that line in the import code, tried below but didn't work. With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
ws.Columns("A:N").WrapText = False
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
     .Refresh
End With

Comment: *"don't want to manually go into the CSV file"* - the CSV file is not what you preformat. Your Excel workbook where you import the CSV into needs to be preformatted. If you have many of them, which all have a wrongly formatted column N, just add `ws.Columns("N:N").WrapText = False` as the last line to the code you posted in your question.

Comment: I agree. The CSV file is fine, nor is there anything you can do to it to make a difference. It's an excel rendering issue. You need to untick all the wrap text setting. You can do this from VBA. I doubt there is a parameter in QueryTables for it because its purely formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this. Because of the text wrap in the source CSV file,
QueryTables will not work because it creates a link/connection to the source file, tried to edit the connection to fix the wrapped text and also tried to put "ws.Columns("N:N").WrapText = False" as the last line in my code, but that did not work either.
There was no issue in the target file, its the source CSV file that had the issue with the wrapped text.

So used good old Text to Columns. This all works fine now, thanks all for your comments and help. Sometimes its good to take all this in, take a break, think about it and I remembered I used CSV converters a while ago (Before Power Query) and just redid some of that code. Code copies the data from the CSV file including the wrapped text, pastes this to a sheet called "Import", I then unwrap text for that entire sheet, then paste that onto a target sheet and then wrap the text again! (Makes it easier for user to read comments) but AFTER formulas have read off the unwrapped text. The problem with QueryTables is that it was taking the wrapped text and splitting it over 4 rows causing errors on the Target sheet with formulas. I could find no way to fix this other than getting the data from the source CSV file and massaging per above.

**Here is all the code:**

```
Sub CSV_Import()

Dim FileType As String, Title As String, CSVWkBkName As String, EEWkBkName As String
Dim CurrentBook As Variant, FileLoc_OpenCSV As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call ClearData

Set CurrentBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
EEWkBkName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name

FileType = "CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv,"
Title = "Please select CSV file:"
FileLoc_OpenCSV = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:=FileType, Title:=Title)

If Not FileLoc_OpenCSV = False Then
Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLoc_OpenCSV).RunAutoMacros Which:=xlAutoOpen
Set CurrentBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
CSVWkBkName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name

Windows(CSVWkBkName).Activate 'move to CSV file
Sheets(1).Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), _
    Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), Array(10, 2), Array(11, 2), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 2)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Range("A1:N1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows(EEWkBkName).Activate
Sheets("Import").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A2").Select
Windows(CSVWkBkName).Activate
ActiveWindow.Close 'close CSV file

Else
Msg = "No file selected, you must select a file for program to run"
Style = vbCritical
Title = "Need to Select File"
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
End If

'copy and paste data from Import sheet to WalkData sheet after massage Import sheet data
Sheets("Import").Activate
Cells.Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = True
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

'paste data to WalkData sheet
Range("A1").Select
LRow_Master = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Range("A2:N" & LRow_Master).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("WalkData").Activate
Range("E2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
Columns("R:R").Select
Selection.WrapText = True
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Range("R1").Select
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Columns("C:Q").Select
 With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .ShrinkToFit = True
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
 End With

Range("A2").Select

'populate formulas on WalkData sheet
Sheets("WalkData").Select
Range("A2").Select
LRow_Master = Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row
NameConcatFormula = "=CONCATENATE(ROW()-1,""."","" "",E2,"" "",F2)"
Range("A2").Select
Range("A2").Value = NameConcatFormula
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LRow_Master) 'fill formulas down
NeedLiftFormula = "=IFERROR(IFS(AND(N2=""Yes"",O2=""Yes""),""No"",N2=""No"",""Yes"",AND(N2=""Yes"",O2=""No""),""Yes""),""Error"")"
Range("C2").Select
Range("C2").Value = NeedLiftFormula
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & LRow_Master) 'fill formulas down
Range("A2").Select

'populate the sign in sheet by linking in to Import sheet
Sheets("SignIn").Select
Range("A9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WalkData!R[-7]C"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A9:A" & LRow_Master + 7)

Sheets("SignIn").Select
Range("A9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WalkData!R[-7]C[4]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A9:A" & LRow_Master + 7)

Range("B9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WalkData!R[-7]C[4]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B9:B" & LRow_Master + 7)

Range("D9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WalkData!R[-7]C[4]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D9:D" & LRow_Master + 7)

Range("E9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WalkData!R[-7]C[6]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E9:E" & LRow_Master + 7)

Range("F9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WalkData!R[-7]C[6]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F9:F" & LRow_Master + 7)

Range("G9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WalkData!R[-7]C[6]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G9:G" & LRow_Master + 7)

Range("H9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WalkData!R[-7]C[9]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H9:H" & LRow_Master + 7)

'format the Sign In sheet
Range("A1").Select
LRow_Master = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Range("A9:H" & LRow_Master).Select
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

Sheets("Import").Visible = False 'user does not need to see this

Range("A9").Select
Msg = "Walk Data Imported"
Style = vbInformation
Title = "Import Complete"
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
Msg = "Problem with file format or data please check and rerun!"
Style = vbError
Title = "File Error!"
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
Sub ClearData()

On Error Resume Next

Sheets("Import").Visible = True
Sheets("Import").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Clear
Range("A1").Select

Sheets("WalkData").Activate
Range("E2").Select
LRow_Master = Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row
Range("A2:R" & LRow_Master).Select
Selection.Clear
Range("A2").Select

Sheets("SignIn").Activate
Range("A9").Select
LRow_Master = Range("A9").End(xlDown).Row
Range("A9:I" & LRow_Master).Select
Selection.Clear
Range("A9").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Excel to intervene into the formatting process of a CSV import, and make sure the content will stay in the cells even when the imported text file is moved or deleted later, it is better to do the CSV parsing completely by some  VBA parsing routine instead of the `QueryTable` approach.

This will require more code, but you find a lot of existing solutions on the Web, like these here:

- https://sitestory.dk/excel_vba/csv-file-import.htm
- http://www.homeandlearn.org/open_a_text_file_in_vba.html

As a bonus, you get full control over the specific delimiters and encoding of any special characters in the CSV.

Another approach is to implement some code which opens the CSV as a separate workbook (using the `Workbook.Open` method), then use some loops and formatting code to copy the content into the places where you want it. See here for an example:

- http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?62448-Import-csv-file

Comment: Thanks Doc, let me explore that appreciate your help.